# "Replay" feature (repeat / rewind)

Tags: x11, recording, screencasting

This occurred to me playing some games where there is no live rewind feature.

Basically what I'm looking for is an application which records the screen, and - when pressing a shortcut - rewinds what it has recorded in the last 10 seconds and then jumps back to normal.

Is there an app which can do this? Or is this achievable in another way?

Comment: wait, I'm not talking about recording terminal output. I mean an actual x server

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: We have a bunch of questions about [tag:screencasting] but I can't find a plain “what program can I use”. Do you want to record the whole game session, or do you want a rolling recording where anything older than X seconds is automatically erased? Do you want to record the whole screen or just one window?

Comment: @Gilles well, I don't really care about the details, I just need to go back 10 seconds instantly on a press of a button and then switch back without a hassle. I'm playing full screen, so I don't care what it records. Regarding the length: yes, record and automatically delete everything from more than 10 (or 20) seconds ago. I don't want to use it after the session, just skip back a little bit every now and then to rewatch a play if I missed something